# How to Install Latest version of Tensorflow in the Anaconda environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda3

My project required application of latest version of Tensorflow(2.15.0). In order to install, I created a new environment with Python3.11.8 using Anaconda Navigator. Among the 'Not Installed' packages, Tensorflow-2.10.0 is shown. I also tried to install outside the Navigator using the command.

```
conda install conda-forge::tensorflow
```

Still the version getting installed is 2.10.0. How can I install Tensorflow-2.15.0 in the Anaconda environment?

Comment: There's probably a reason conda isn't installing 2.15.0 - but if i understand correctly you want to install a specific version, so does `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=2.15.0` work?

Comment: `py -m pip install tensorflow --upgrade` Released: Mar 8, 2024

Comment: Yes I tried the conda install command as given by Ukulele and the response given below.
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - tensorflow=2.15.0*

Comment: I had to stop using Anaconda and switched to VSCode. I could install all packages with the latest versions and all fine so far.